# PHP file to delete string in database between two strings

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to delete a string from a database (of Wordpress posts) that starts with `<noindex>` and ends with `</noindex>`. The string is not always the same between those strings.

I found a PHP script that seems to old and doesn't work, it requires some fixes (like msqli) and I have no idea, I'm just trying to clean viruses from a database:

```
<?php

$co = mysql_connect("localhost", "MY_USER", "MY_PASS");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db("MY_DB", $co);

$selectQuery = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM wp_posts";

$res = mysql_query($selectQuery, $co) or exit(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '" . addslashes(preg_replace("<noindex>(.*)</noindex>", '', $row['post_content'])) . "' WHERE ID = " . $row['ID'];
    mysql_query($updateQuery) or exit(mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($co);

?>
```

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't vote me down, I'm trying to make the best here with little time and I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: Is there only ever 1 instance of `<noindex> ... </noindex>` per post or could it appear many times?

Comment: yes, there's only one instance per post.

Comment: It's a bit hacky (read, a lot hacky), but with newer versions of MySQL you can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function like `SELECT t.id, REGEXP_REPLACE(t.post_content, '<noindex>.*</noindex>', '') AS content FROM wp_posts AS t`

Comment: Should I do that in PhpMyAdmin? Thank you.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, if you want to update all the records, you can just do `UPDATE wp_posts AS t SET t.post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(t.post_content, '<noindex>.*</noindex>', '')` ... backup the table first to be on the safe side though!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, I will go try it now!

Comment: Just had to correct my table/column names - I'd tested the query on a local DB table to check it works but forgot to map the names back to WP for your system... it *should* work now.

Comment: Use prepared statements, and start learning by writing the code and understand what you're doing. Pasting old code here and asking for a fix is not helping you learning the language. I recommend PDO as a database driver. Learn it one time and you can communicate with all kinds of databases instead of just one using mysqli.

Comment: CD001, unfortunately it looks like I have an old MySQL version: FUNCTION dbname.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist.

@Xorifelse, you are right. I was just in a hurry to clean this website, that's why I seemed indifferent or maybe lazy. I assure you I'm not.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code:-
<?php
$co = mysqli_connect("localhost", "MY_USER", "MY_PASS");
mysqli_set_charset($co,'utf8');
mysqli_select_db("MY_DB", $co);
$selectQuery = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM wp_posts";
$res = mysqli_query($co,$selectQuery) or exit(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '" . addslashes(preg_replace("<noindex>(.*)</noindex>", '', $row['post_content'])) . "' WHERE ID = " . $row['ID'];
    mysqli_query($co,$updateQuery) or exit(mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_close($co);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to rewrite the code. There seem to be 2 small errors reported: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli on line 4 --AND--
mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given on line 6

Comment: I did a change myself, inversed "MY_DB" with $co, and it might have worked.

Comment: unfortunately, the whole content disappeared from the website :((

Comment: i put it back from my backup in phpmyadmin. seems there's something wrong with the code, unfortunately.